# Apache not return Laravel json validation errors on Test but works on Dev

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation

I've been working on a Laravel API with validation. I'm sending this request to the server:

```
> POST /api/v1/clients HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost
> User-Agent: insomnia/2022.3.0
> Content-Type: application/json
> Accept: application/json
> Authorization: Bearer ***************
> Content-Length: 16

{
 "name": "",
}
```

On my development system, running windows/Apache/PHP 8.1, the POST requests return a JSON object containing validation errors.

```json
{
    "message": "The name field is required.",
    "errors": {
        "name": [
            "The name field is required."
        ]
    }
}
```

But my test system, running Linux/Apache/PHP 8.1, does not return a JSON response:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>422 Unprocessable Content</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Unprocessable Content</h1>
<p>The server understands the media type of the
request entity, but was unable to process the
contained instructions.</p>
</body></html>
```

Here is my code:

api.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:sanctum', 'prefix' => 'v1'], function () {
    Route::apiResource('clients', ClientApiController::class);
});
```

StoreClientRequest.php

```php
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
    ];
}
```

ClientAPIController.php

```
public function store(StoreClientRequest $request)
{
    $client = Client::create($request->all())->fresh();

    return (new ClientResource($client))->response()->setStatusCode(201);
}
```

Since it's working on my localhost I don't believe it is the code. I'm guessing it's an issue with Apache or PHP configuration on the Test server but I'm not seeing anything different as far as I can tell. As one is Windows and the other Linux, it's not straight forward to check the differences.

Any reason I'm not getting a JSON response back from the test server?

Comment: Add the header 'accept:application/json'  to request . if its not working
 add the network request section of browser in question ....which help a lot to figure out the issue

Comment: That header is already in the request.  See above

Comment: @miken32 - Thanks, It is required, I'm looking to return a message back to indicate why the request has failed. There are more fields than name, some required some not.  I've removed them from here for simplicity.  It is working on my Dev (localhost) and the response returns the required fields that are missing but it's not working on the Test server.

Comment: Ok understood. I cleaned up your question to make it clear you're showing a different behaviour between dev and test. Can you include the route definition; I assume it's in `api.php` with standard middleware applied? What version of Laravel are you using? The same on both systems?

Comment: And this is unlikely to be a server issue. Is the request being made from the same host with the same configuration in both instances?

Comment: Thanks miken32, I've only been working with Laravel a few of months. Yes, it's in api.php with the standard middleware, I'll add it to the question. It's Laravel 9 (upgraded from 8) and it's the same on both.  I updated to 9 about a month ago and Test was just installed a week ago. The request is been made to 2 different hosts. Dev is my windows PC as localhost and Test is an AWS Linux server.

Comment: I'm wondering if the request is being made *from* the same host both times

Comment: Sorry, yes, I'm using insomnia on my PC to POST the request to both servers.

Comment: Not sure then, have you tried dumping the request headers to make sure they're as expected? `protected function prepareForValidation() {dd($this->headers->all());}` in StoreClientRequest.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does appear to be an issue with Apache dropping the body of the response when using php-fpm.  I tested a couple of different configurations of Apache, Nginx, mod-php, and php-fpm.

| Server | PHP | Response body |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apache | mod-php | Included |
| Apache | php-fpm | Missing |
| Nginx | php-fpm | Included |

I found a few links with an issue with the request body being drop so may be the same thing or something similar.

https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2017/apache-fastcgi-proxyfcgi-and-empty-post-bodies-chunked-transfer

Looks like I will need to upgrade the other apps to PHP 8 so I can switch back to mod-php or move to nginx.  Thanks for the help everyone.